# JQuery: .not() method doesn't exclude objects from collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop several span elements and get text from them. But I want to exclude from the result text, that is in elements with a specific class.

Example:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
       <script>
           $( document ).ready(function(){
               $('.x').each(function(index, value){
                   console.log($(this).not($('.y')).text());
               });
           });
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <span class="x">text1</span>
       <span class="x">text2<span class="y">error</span></span>
       <span class="x">text3</span>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
text1
text2error
text3
```

How can I exclude .y from .x? Desired output: text1text2text3

Example is on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fBj2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `.contents()` at this context,

```
 $('.x').each(function(index, value){
   console.log($(this).contents(":not('.y')").text());
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/2fBj2/2/)

As per your desired result,

```
console.log($('.x').contents(':not(.y)').text());
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/2fBj2/3/)

Comment: Thanks, this works in a proper way, but it still unclear for me, why not() method fails.

Comment: You can use `.not()` over a collection, but not on a single element.. And it will not make sense too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning and then getting text,

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('.x').clone().each(function(index, value){
          $('.y',this).remove();
          console.log($(this).text())
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2fBj2/1/)**

*Note : Just a workaround.*

Comment: I think, that clone method have to be used in inextricable way, because you have to waste double amount of RAM.